# How to get a javascript function to execute only once on dom ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting alerted "hi" over and over again, how do I get it to do it once and stop:

```
function doSomething() {
   alert('hi');
}

$(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML where you are including the JavaScript file you posted?

Comment: I don't see the same behavior.  Here's a sample fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/BjbEM/

Comment: i guess the OP wants the function to run once when the page is rendered first time and after that on page refresh the OP doesn't want the function to run?

Answer (score 17):

```
        // Fired once when document is ready
        $(document).one('ready', function () {
              doSomething();
        });
```

Using .one ensures this is done only once and not repeatedly.It is okay to put several document.ready event listeners (if you need other events to execute multiple times) as long as you do not overdo it, for the sake of readability.

.one is especially useful when you want the alert to appear the first time a web page is opened or when a mobile application is installed the first time.

Answer (score 3):

I think you include your JS file multiple times from the HTML. Clean up your HTML.

---

Using:

```
$(function(){
});
```

is perfectly normal. Using more verbose form have no benefit. If you are writing a plugin, you might want to do this:

```
function($){
    // $ always refers to jQuery here
    ...        

}(jQuery);
// $ might not be defined here in compatibility mode.
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion,  to check if the JS is being included more than once. The advantage of the more verbose `$(document).ready` form is that it makes it explicit what you're doing, especially to coders who don't know jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
window.onload = function() {
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: He's using jQuery, it's preferable to call it on `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to do something like this?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is ... with using cookie - like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie("blocker") == 1) {
        //your code or without code;
        return;
    } else {
        //your code for first time
        $.cookie("blocker", 1, {
            expires: 1 / 24 / 60 //time, this is one minut
        });
    }
});
```

This code is good if you have smarty on your page

Answer (score 0):

Raul is right, it would help to have the code...

But based on my experience with this, what you want is something more along the lines of:

```
var doSomething = function() {
  alert('hi');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to stick to the more verbose style:

```
function doSomething() {
   alert('hi');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: While I agree with this style decision, it has nothing to do with his question

Comment: @Matt: you're right, this was hardly worth an answer rather than a comment. I just wanted to show the alternative style properly formatted -- wondering if the more terse form was hiding some error (not shown in the original post).